# Modeling SAR origin-destination flows?

Tags: r, regression, r-sp, o-d-matrix

I would like to model SAR Origin-Destination (migration) flows using [the
model specification proposed by LeSage & Pace] (http://www4.fe.uc.pt/spatial/doc/lecture7.pdf) (p.8, equation [10]):

[image]

Where *o* stands for origin and *d* for destination.

I think one could call this model a *spatial autoregressive interaction model*.

What is crucial about the model is, that we have the spatially lagged
responses of the origin **AND** the destination, as well as the spatially
lagged predictors of the origin **AND** the destination in the SAR equation.

---

- Do you have any ideas how to implement such a model in R?
- Is there a way to specify a `spdep::lagsarlm` in that specific or at least in a similar way or should I use a different package/function? As far as I can see there `spdep::lagsarlm` allows only for **ONE** `listw` argument.

Comment: `install.packages(sos); library(sos); findFn('LeSage Pace')`

Comment: `findFn('LeSage Pace')` unfortunately could not find what I want /-: I think I need to model it manually...but I don't know how...maybe with `glm`?